# what is 以及与? is it "and + and", if so why use such a thing?

Tags: conjunction

I've been reading a book and stumbled upon what looks like a double conjunction 以及与:

> 他们惊讶地发现，虽然属于不同的时代，但那些动植物相互之间，**以及与**现代生物之间都有许多相似之处.

Is this a mistake? If not, then surely author differenciates between 以及 and 与, he gives them different functions. What are those functions?

Is there an alternative way to form such a sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 他们惊讶地发现，虽然属于不同的时代，但那些动植物相互之间，以及与现代生物之间都有许多相似之处.

'以及' means "and also";

"与"  means "and".

Let's break the sentence apart and see what's missing:

- **那些动植物**相互之间 (between **those animals and plants** themselves)
- 以及 (and also)
- between (*subject omitted*) 与 (and) 现代生物之间 (modern living things)
- 都有许多相似之处. (all have many similarities)

The author wanted to say:

Those (ancient) animals and plants had many similarities between themselves; and also have many similarities between them and modern living things

It would be more clear if he didn't omit the repeated subject

[那些动植物相互之间]，[以及] [(*那些动植物*)与现代生物之间] [都有许多相似之处]

[between those animals and plants themselves]，[and also] [between (*those animals and plants*) and modern living things] [all have many similarities ]

*the repeated subject (那些动植物) was omitted*

Answer (score 4):

"以及" means "as well as" or "also"
"与" means "with" or 'to'

The sentence translates to:

To their surprise, they found out that, despite belonging to different ages, those organisms  bear a strong resemblance to each other, as well as to  modern-day ones.